# Java remove data that is duplicated

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Is it possible to get all the distinct values in an arraylist or hashmap?

Let's say for example I have elements on arraylist like this :

```
123, 123, 456, 123, 456, 000
```

And in HashMap :

```
123, test1
123, test2
456, test3
123, test4
000, test5
```

Comment: Use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) in that case; I don't know how are you able to store `123` again as a key in a `Map`

Comment: I'm just assuming if it's possible to put duplicate Keys in HashMap.

Comment: Sets (like HashSet) are collections of distinct elements.

Comment: HashMap can't have duplicate values for same key. User guava MultiMap for that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `Map`, by definition the keys will be unique.  For implementations of `List` there are a few options.  For Java 5 through Java 7

```
public <T> List<T> removeDuplicates(List<T> list){
    Set<T> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
    return new ArrayList<>(set);
}
```

With Java 8

```
public <T> List<T> removeDuplicatesJava8(List<T> list){
    return list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: How about with Java 6?

Comment: see the first example.  "pre-java8" means anything before java 8.  That would include java 6.

Comment: Oh oops sorry, I didnt see that one.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this @MadConan. So it's better to use Java 8 because it has distinct method.

Answer (score 4):

Keys should be unique in HashMap. if you are choosing duplicate keys then existing key value will be replace with new value.

if you want to avoid duplicate then use `Set`.

Comment: What will happen if I'm gonna read a text file and put it on HashMap, my text file has multiple data.

Comment: In HashMap it will override last value so you will able to see last value you have added for the same key.

Comment: So in short, the existing key will be replaced with another key that same as that key. Right?

Comment: Existing key is replaced with new one. That means you lost your existing key data.

Answer (score 0):

HashMaps don't allow duplicate keys. If you enter a key which is already there then it replaces it with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map<K, List<V>>` (or `Map<K, V[]>`) if you like to map multiple values to a key:

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
    add(data, 123, "test1");
    add(data, 123, "test2");
    add(data, 456, "test3");
    add(data, 123, "test4");
    add(data,   0, "test5");
    data.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
}

static <K, V> void add(Map<K, List<V>> listMap, K key, V value) {
    List<V> values = listMap.get(key);
    if(values == null) {
        values = new ArrayList<V>();
        listMap.put(key, values);
    }
    values.add(value);
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 -> [test5]
456 -> [test3]
123 -> [test1, test2, test4]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this one, I understand now how Set and HashMap works!

Comment: @tuturyokgaming You should upvote any answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

To get a `Collection` of unique elements from a `List` you can do that

```
Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>(nonUniqueList);
```